# How to perform a join of two sets and populate navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have two classes, `Teapot` and `Cup`:

```
public class Teapot
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id", TypeName = "int")]
    public int Id         { get; set; }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }

    public int ColorId    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MaterialId")]
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ColorId")]
    public virtual Color    Color    { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Cup
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id", TypeName = "int")]
    public int Id         { get; set; }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }

    public int ColorId    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MaterialId")]
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ColorId")]
    public virtual Color    Color    { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
namespace ViewModel.Data
{
    public class TeapotsWithInfo
    {
        public Model.Data.Teapot Teapot { get; set; }
        public Model.Data.Cup    Cup    { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

For my `ViewModel`, I need to perform a join on MaterialId and ColorId and to have some navigation propeties like `Teapot.Material.Manufacturer` included. So, I've tried following queries:

1. This throws "LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types"

   ```
   (from t in db.Teapots
    join c in db.Cups
    on new { t.MaterialId, t.ColorId } equals new { c.MaterialId, c.ColorId }
    where t.Id == id
    select new ViewModel.Data.TeapotsWithInfo { Teapot = t, Cup = c })
       .Include(t => t.Material.Manufacturer).SingleOrDefault();
   ```
2. This seems to ignore the `Include`

   ```
    (from t in db.Teapots.Include(t => t.Material.Manufacturer)
    join c in db.Cups
    on new { t.MaterialId, t.ColorId } equals new { c.MaterialId, c.ColorId }
    where t.Id == id
    select new ViewModel.Data.TeapotsWithInfo { Teapot = t, Cup = c }).SingleOrDefault();
   ```

Now I found some answers here that suggest to enumerate and then to perform another select, but I'd rather catch the data in one go.

Comment: what do you mean by "one go"? if you enumerate then select, you'd only be sending a single database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having difficulties including navigation properties because queries with joins or projections ignore eager loading (see [this](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2009/02/entity-framework-how-to-prevent-eager.html)).

Unfortunately, you will need to do what you seem to be avoiding: pull the data from the database first, then do an additional select to build your ViewModel (which will have the relationships loaded from the original query). The additional select should be a rather trivial operation, though, since you're not performing an additional load from the database, and the enumerable should only contain a single item.

```
(from t in db.Teapots.Include(t => t.Material.Manufacturer)
 join c in db.Cups
 on new { t.MaterialId, t.ColorId } equals new { c.MaterialId, c.ColorId }
 where t.Id == id
 select new 
  {
     Teapot = t,
     Cup = c,
     Material = t.Material,
     Manufacturer = t.Material.Manufacturer,
  })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(a => new ViewModel.Data.TeapotsWithInfo 
  { 
     Teapot = a.Teapot, 
     Cup = a.Cup 
  })
.SingleOrDefault();
```

**Source**

- http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/use-projections-and-a-repository-to-fake-a-filtered-eager-load/